# Angular display account login in navbar

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I am trying to get the login name of a user to put it in a navbar `component`.
I first added only the lines without `eventManager`, but I was not able to see the user name without refreshing the webpage, so I decided to use the below method, but I am not sure how to see if I make a broadcast.
So I decided to use `jhipster` build in event manager. I created `broadcast` and a `subscribe`.

Is there a better way?

```
this.eventManager.subscribe('userLoggedIn', () => {
  console.log('userLoggedIn called');
  this.accountService.identity().subscribe(account => {
     this.loggedinAccount = account.login;
  });
});
```

Comment: can you please post all your navbar component? by login name you mean populating `this.loggedinAccount`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nMX948Y1

Comment: yes just want to show the username login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default JHipster template actually displays the account login on the home component (landing page). I think it's easier if you just use `getAuthenticationState()` like they do.

Changes required in your `navbar.component.ts` to retrieve the authentication state:

```js
import { Account } from 'app/core/user/account.model';
// ...
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // ...
  account: Account | null = null;
  authSubscription?: Subscription;

  // constructor

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ...
    this.authSubscription = this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(
      account => (this.account = account)
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.authSubscription) {
      this.authSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

And in your `navbar.component.html` you can use `account.login` however you want, e.g.:

```html
<span class="text-light" *ngIf="isAuthenticated()">
  Welcome {{account.login}} !
</span>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but the only value is displaying is the ID.
it has displayName, name , but when i use them its empty only the ID appears to be working :/

``displayName: string;
    id: string;
    imageURL?: string;
    name?: string;
    rpDisplayName: string;``

Comment: It seems you are importing the wrong `Account` interface. I have updated my answer with the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a broadcast subscribe, but use this:

```
loggedinAccount = 'Login';

//...
ngOnInit(): {
//...
    this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', () => {
        this.accountService.identity().subscribe(account => {
            this.loggedinAccount = account.login;
        });
    });
}
```

authenticationSuccess is already define from JHipster in user-management.json. 
So, just use it.

in HTML

```
    <span *ngIf="isAuthenticated()">
        <fa-icon icon="user"></fa-icon>
        <span>{{loggedinAccount}}</span>
    </span>
```